# How to sum these datas in the column?(Using R)

Tags: r

How to use R do this coding?
I have a dataframe which containes two columns  "data"  and "dataSums".  The values of these two columnes are as follow. You can see the picture of the dataframe.

---

[image]

The explaination is as below.

If the value in the first column "data" is 1 , then the value in the second  column "dataSum" is the sum of all the row till now in the first column.

That is

- If  row 1 of "data"  is 1 , then row 1 of "dataSum" is 1.
- If  row 2 of "data"  is 1 , then row 2 of "dataSum" is 1+1=2.
- If  row 3 of "data"  is 1 , then row 3 of "dataSum" is 1+1+1=3.
- If  row 5 of "data"  is 1 , then row 3 of "dataSum" is 1+1+1+0+1=4.
- If  row 7 of "data"  is 1 , then row 3 of "dataSum" is 1+1+1+0+1+0+1=5.
- If the value in the first column "data" is 0 , then the value in the second  column "dataSum" is 0.

How to use R do this coding?  Many thanks!

Comment: In your question, your desired dataset is a but confusing. You appear to already have the dataset you are describing in your bullet points. Are you intentionally replacing row 3 multiple times given a condition? You say you want row 3 of `dataSum` replaced if rows 3, 5, and 7 are 1. Was this a mistake, or are you only focused on row 3? What should rows 4 and 6 look like?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @WhatIf solution, you could also do the following ways, assuming your data is `df`

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(df, dataSum=if_else(data==1, cumsum(data),0))
```

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, dataSum:=fifelse(data==1, cumsum(data),0)]
```

Output:

```
    data dataSum
   <num>   <num>
1:     1       1
2:     1       2
3:     1       3
4:     0       0
5:     1       4
6:     0       0
7:     1       5
```